# get value of the string stored in a variable, whose name stored as string in another variable

Tags: freemarker

```
<#assign blah = "foo">
<#assign foo = "awesome">
```

Can we render "awesome" without referencing foo ?

I tried something like `${${blah}}`

But it isn't working, any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [`eval`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_eval) built-in which evaluates a string as an FTL expression.

In your case use it like this:

```
${blah?eval}
```

Comment: Or, since this is not a generic expression but a variable name, `${.vars[blah]}`. It's faster than `?eval` because the value of `blah` doesn't have to parsed.