# Freemarker read dynamic properties

Tags: dynamic, freemarker

I have a list of variables' suffixes such as: "mono", "uni", "kid"

These should be appended to a variable name (bike_) and used such as:

```
${item.bike_mono!}
${item.bike_uni!}
${item.bike_kid!}
```

I tried playing around with the [freemarker's interpret built-in](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_interpret) but no success.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21276930/1700321.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use square brackets to access them. So if your object looks like this

```
Map<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
item.put("bike_mono", "Mono");
item.put("bike_uni", "Uni");
item.put("bike_kid", "Kid");
model.addAttribute("item", item);
```

Your template can access it like this

```
<#assign suffixes=["mono", "uni", "kid"]>
<#assign prefix="bike_">
<#list suffixes as suffix>
    ${item[prefix+suffix]!}
</#list>
```