# How to process freemarker template from variable inside template?

Tags: freemarker

Simple example:

```
<div>${item.content}</div>
```

But inside of `item.content` variable may exist another template code, such as

`<#if otherItem.image??><div class ...>...</#if>`

Is that possible to tell freemarker compile this code inside variable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/21276930/1700321.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?interpret` creates a directive from a string. Note that it doesn't call the directive. Expressions that evaluate to directive can be called with `<@someExpression />`. Putting these together you get:

```
<div><@item.content?interpret /></div>
```